# Selecting multiple events on resource timeline/scheduler

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Is there a way to select multiple events on the resource timeline/scheduler?

I have been looking at all the docs and can't find anything! Is this a feature?

Comment: No there's no specific feature for this. Check the feature requests on the fullCalendar GitHub in case anyone requested it already, then you can vote for it - or even contribute some code to make it happen! Why do you need to be able to select multiple events at once?